# C# - AESCng Why Encrypt/Decrypt byte array greater than 127 incorrectly?

Tags: c#, aes

when I encrypt and decrypt byte[128] { 1, 2, ..., 126, 127 } by AES, everything is fine:

```
// Create Key & iv
byte[] key = GenerateKey();
byte[] iv = GenerateIV();

// Create raw byte array 0-127
byte[] raw = new byte[128];
for (byte i = 0; i < 128; i++)
{
    raw[i] = i;
}

// Encrypt
var encrypted = Encrypt(raw, key, iv);
// Decrypt
var decrypted = Decrypt(encrypted, key, iv);
```

decrypted will output byte[128] { 1, 2, ..., 126, 127 }.
but when I change raw to byte[127] { 128, 129, ..., 253, 254 } to the same encrypt/decrypt logic, result becomes to byte[381], inside is loops of [239, 191, 189]:

```
// Create Key & iv
byte[] key = GenerateKey();
byte[] iv = GenerateIV();

// Create raw byte array 128-254    
byte[] raw = new byte[127];
for (byte i = 128; i <= 254; i++)
{
    raw[i-128] = i;
}

// Encrypt
var encrypted = Encrypt(raw, key, iv);
// Decrypt
var decrypted = Decrypt(encrypted, key, iv);
```

now decrypted will output byte[381] { 239, 191, 189, ..., 239, 191, 189 }

at start I thought that over 127 is different, until I've found the following byte array also work:

```
// Create Key & iv
byte[] key = GenerateKey();
byte[] iv = GenerateIV();

// Create raw byte array from Poruguese ÇÃ
string rawPortuguese = "ÇÃ";
byte[] raw = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(rawPortuguese);
```

now the raw is byte[4] { 195, 135, 195, 131 }, every digit is greater than 127.

```
// Encrypt
var encrypted = Encrypt(raw, key, iv);
// Decrypt
var decrypted = Decrypt(encrypted, key, iv);
```

but also can decrypt correctly, decrypted is byte[4] { 195, 135, 195, 131 }
now I totally confused, why raw data byte[127] { 128, 129, ..., 253, 254 } cannot decrypt correctlly?

Key/IV/Encrypt/Decrypt code:

```
static byte[] GenerateKey()
{
    using (AesCng cng = new AesCng())
    {
        cng.GenerateKey();
        return cng.Key;
    }
}

static byte[] GenerateIV()
{
    using (AesCng cng = new AesCng())
    {
        cng.GenerateIV();
        return cng.IV;
    }
}

static byte[] Encrypt(byte[] raw, byte[] key, byte[] iv, CipherMode mode = CipherMode.CBC, PaddingMode padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7)
{
    byte[] encrypted;

    using (AesCng cng = new AesCng())
    {
        cng.Mode = mode;
        cng.Padding = padding;

        cng.Key = key;
        cng.IV = iv;

        using (ICryptoTransform encryptor = cng.CreateEncryptor())
        using (MemoryStream msEncrypt = new MemoryStream())
        {
            using (CryptoStream csEncrypt = new CryptoStream(msEncrypt, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
            {
                csEncrypt.Write(raw, 0, raw.Length);
            }

            encrypted = msEncrypt.ToArray();
        }
    }

    return encrypted;
}

static byte[] Decrypt(byte[] encrypted, byte[] key, byte[] iv, CipherMode mode = CipherMode.CBC, PaddingMode padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7)
{
    byte[] decryptedData;
    string plaintext = null;
    byte[] plainData = null;

    using (AesCng cng = new AesCng())
    {
        cng.Mode = mode;
        cng.Padding = padding;

        cng.Key = key;
        decryptedData = encrypted;
        cng.IV = iv;

        using (ICryptoTransform decryptor = cng.CreateDecryptor())
        {
            using (MemoryStream msDecrypt = new MemoryStream(decryptedData))
            {
               using (CryptoStream csDecrypt = new CryptoStream(msDecrypt, decryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Read))
               {
                    using (StreamReader srDecrypt = new StreamReader(csDecrypt))
                    {
                        plaintext = srDecrypt.ReadToEnd();
                    }
                    plainData = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(plaintext);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return plainData;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the problem:

```
using (StreamReader srDecrypt = new StreamReader(csDecrypt))
{
    plaintext = srDecrypt.ReadToEnd();
}
plainData = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(plaintext);
```

You're treating the plain-text data as if it's UTF-8, converting it to a string, then converting it back to bytes (using UTF-8 again). That's fine if the plain-text data really *is* UTF-8-encoded text (as it is in your Portuguese example), but that's not the case for an arbitrary byte array. The byte sequence 0x80, 0x81, 0x82, 0x83...0xff isn't valid UTF-8.

Unless you know that data is valid text, you shouldn't treat it as text - that always leads to problems like this. The name "plain text" in this case doesn't really mean *text* - it's an unfortunate bit of terminology. It just means "not-encrypted data".

If you just want to effectively read from an arbitrary stream and create an array from it, use another `MemoryStream`, copy the data to that, then use `MemoryStream.ToArray` to convert it to a `byte[]`:

```
using (CryptoStream csDecrypt = new CryptoStream(msDecrypt, decryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Read))
{
    using (var plainData = new MemoryStream())
    {
        csDescrypt.CopyTo(plainData);
        return plainData.ToArray();
    }
}
```