# File corrupted on download from Controller Action

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am generating some JSON content, and then GZipping that content, before returning the gzipped content to the user, from an MVC Controller Action.

The generation of the content, and gzipping, is working correctly as I can output the generated file to disk, and then I can open that file using GZip.  However, when the content is returned to the browser, the content has been corrupted.

I have tried several different approaches to returning the content to the browser, such as

```
return File(byte[], "application/gzip");

return new FileStreamResult(stream, "application/gzip")
```

And also writing directly to the Response using BinaryWrite() and WriteFile() methods

No matter what I do, the file I receive in the browser is corrupt.

This code shows the manner in which I am currently trying to return the file content.

```
// This line writes my content byte[] array to disk.  This file when opened with gzip works fine.
System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(@"C:\temp\test.vcp", result.FileBytes);


// Writing out the byte array to the Response results in a corrupt file.  I have also attempted to Response.WriteFile(@"C:\temp\test.vcp") which also results in a corrupt file.

Response.Clear();
Response.ContentType = "application/gzip";

Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", cd.ToString());
Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", result.FileBytes.Length.ToString());

Response.BinaryWrite(result.FileBytes);
Response.Flush();
Response.Close();
Response.End();
```

As the file I am creating can be written to disk, and can be read using Gzip, but the file received by the browser is corrupt, I am confident that my file creation is OK.  But somehow after writing the file to the Response, it is being corrupted.

I did wonder if maybe some sort of HTTPHandler is manipulating the result, but I haven't added any Handlers (that I can see).

I am running the application locally currently through IISExpress.  How can I check what HttpHandlers/HttpModules are being applied to the pipeline?

Ultimately I expect to receive the exact same file in my browser as is written to disk.

For reference, my generated content is 132 bytes in length, but the browser receives 216 bytes.  I have noticed when looking at the byte structure of the received data, there is a repeating pattern of 3 bytes in the content, with the values 239, 191, 189.  It almost looks like the resultant byte array has been stuffed or padded with these 3 bytes.

**EDIT**

Here is a standalone Action method which demonstrated the issue.

```
    [HttpGet]
    public void GetFile()
    {

        byte[] text = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(@"{""PetName"":""Doggy McDocFace"",""OwnerName"":""Kurt""}");
        byte[] compressed = Compress(text);

        var cd = new System.Net.Mime.ContentDisposition
        {
            // for example foo.bak
            FileName = "ExampleFile.vcp",

            // always prompt the user for downloading, set to true if you want 
            // the browser to try to show the file inline
            Inline = true,
        };


        System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(@"C:\temp\ExampleFile.vcp", compressed);


        Response.Clear();
        Response.ContentType = "application/gzip";

        Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", cd.ToString());
        Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", compressed.Length.ToString());

        Response.BinaryWrite(compressed);
        Response.Flush();
        Response.Close();
        Response.End();
    }

    public byte[] Compress(byte[] raw)
    {
        using (var memory = new MemoryStream())
        {
            using (var gzip = new GZipStream(memory, CompressionMode.Compress, true))
            {
                gzip.Write(raw, 0, raw.Length);
            }
            return memory.ToArray();
        }
    }
```

Here I am spoofing my JSON content, and then compressing it.  The file written to disk works fine, and can be opened with my GZip application (I use 7-zip).  However, the file received by the browser is corrupt.  7-zip cannot recognise it as a gzip file.

**EDIT 2**

So it looks like (Thanks to @Will) that the content when written to Response is falling foul of UTF-8 encoding.  I cannot work out how though, as in my example above I am using Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes() to convert my string to a byte[] array.

I've tried setting the

```
       Response.Charset = Encoding.ASCII.EncodingName;
       Response.ContentEncoding = Encoding.ASCII;
```

But this still doesn't result in a valid file downloaded.

**Edit 3**

I've narrowed down the issue to the GZip encryption of the data.  If I do not encrypt the data, then the plain text file downloads fine.  However, encrypting the byte[] array and then writing that byte[] array to the Repsonse is resulting in what seems like UTF-8 encoding issues.  Any bytes with a value over 127 are corrupted with the 3 bytes I mention further up.  I cannot work out why the Response is treating this encrypted data in this way.  My assumption is that when the Byte[] array is just plain text as a byte[] array, then this is handled fine.  As soon as it is a proper byte[] array, i.e not just a string as a byte[] array, then some other conversion of encoding is going on in the Response.

Comment: You need to show us your actual code, there's not enough here.

Comment: The above is my actual code, relating to where I write the file out to the Response.  I cannot post my whole code as It's comprised of several implementations of interfaces across several projects in my solution.  What I am saying in the code snippet above is I have a byte[].  I can write that byte[] to disk and it is 132 bytes.  When I return that byte[] to the browser, the received data is 216 bytes, and the resultant file cannot be opened by gzip.  So after writing to the Response, the content is being corrupted.

Comment: Hmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmm https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50692651/c-sharp-aescng-why-encrypt-decrypt-byte-array-greater-than-127-incorrectly "result becomes to byte[381], inside is loops of [239, 191, 189]:"

Comment: oooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooh https://haacked.com/archive/2012/01/30/hazards-of-converting-binary-data-to-a-string.aspx/

Comment: @Will Thanks, that's interesting.  In my above (edit) example, I am using Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes() to convert my string to bytes.  That is still resulting in a valid file when saved to disk, but invalid when returned to the browser via the response.  I admit I was using Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes in my proper (unsimplified) code.

Comment: Try Encoding.Default and see if that helps with the transfer.

Answer (score 0):

You can try `ActionFilterAttribute`
Basically response filters look at the Response output stream as it's written and convert the data flowing through it.

[GZip/Deflate Compression in ASP.NET MVC](https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2012/apr/28/gzipdeflate-compression-in-aspnet-mvc)

```
public class CompressAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {

        var encodingsAccepted = filterContext.HttpContext.Request.Headers["Accept-Encoding"];
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(encodingsAccepted)) return;

        encodingsAccepted = encodingsAccepted.ToLowerInvariant();
        var response = filterContext.HttpContext.Response;

        if (encodingsAccepted.Contains("deflate"))
        {
            response.AppendHeader("Content-encoding", "deflate");
            response.Filter = new DeflateStream(response.Filter, CompressionMode.Compress);
        }
        else if (encodingsAccepted.Contains("gzip"))
        {
            response.AppendHeader("Content-encoding", "gzip");
            response.Filter = new GZipStream(response.Filter, CompressionMode.Compress);
        }
    }
}
```

```
[Compress]
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult GetFile()
{...}
```